# How to setup must exist in database

Tags: mysql, cascade

i need help. As you can see in my tables i have to setup primary and forign keys and i need help on this cascade updates.
For example i have a task like this:
If the value for Category_Name is changed in CATEGORY, the change should be reflected here as well.

But this doesent work :

If an OrderID in ORDERED is changed, then the change should be reflected here as well.
If an ORDERED is deleted, then any LINE_ITEM(s)associated with that order should also be deleted.
If the Item_Number of an ITEM is changed, then the change should be reflected here as well.
I dont know how to setup this correctly and i need help to better understand this.

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST1;
USE TEST1;

CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (
CategoryName VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 

ShippingPerPound CHAR(4),

OffersAlowed ENUM('y', 'n'), 

CONSTRAINT CATEGORY_PK PRIMARY KEY (CategoryName)

) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE ITEM(
ItemNumber INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 

Item_Name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,

Description VARCHAR(255),

Model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

Price CHAR(8) NOT NULL,

parent_ItemNumber INT,

CategoryName VARCHAR(35),

CONSTRAINT ITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ItemNumber),

CONSTRAINT ITEM_CategoryName_fk FOREIGN KEY (CategoryName) REFERENCES 

CATEGORY(CategoryName) ON UPDATE CASCADE) 

ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE table LINE_ITEM(

Quantitiy INT(255),

Shipping_amounth DECIMAL(4,2),

ItemNumber INT UNSIGNED,

OrderID INT UNSIGNED,

CONSTRAINT LINE_ITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY(ItemNumber),

CONSTRAINT LINE_ITEM_PK PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),

CONSTRAINT LINE_ITEM_OrderID FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES ORDERED(OrderID) ON UPDATE CASCADE),

CONSTRAINT LINE_ITEM_OrderID FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES ORDERED(OrderID) ON UPDATE DELETE),

CONSTRAINT LINE_ITEM_ItemNumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (ItemNumber) REFERENCES ITEM(ItemNumber) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE OFFER(

OfferCode varchar(15),

Discount_Amt varchar(35) NOT NULL,

MinAmount DECIMAL(2,2) NOT NULL,

ExpirationDate DATE NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT OFFER_OfferCode PRIMARY KEY(OfferCode)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE ORDERED(

OrderID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,

total_cost DECIMAL(8,2),

CONSTRAINT ORDERED_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),

CONSTRAINT OFFER_OfferCode FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES OFFER(OfferCode) ON UPDATE CASCADE),

CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_CustomerID FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: There are too many issues. You can't define a foregn key referencing a table which isn't defined yet. You can't have two primary keys for one table (though you can define one composite key on multiple columns). You have defined `LINE_ITEM_OrderID` twice. You are trying to define a FK on a non existend column (`OFFER_OfferCode`). And you have some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

> *If the value for Category_Name is changed in CATEGORY, the change should be reflected [in the tables which reference Category] as well.*

You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You've already chosen a solution to your problem (using cascading updates) and asked about that. It's not a good solution, it just papers over the real. Instead, you should ask about the real problem.

The real problem is you have duplicate data, CategoryName is stored in two places. The question is how one deals with that? The answer is to redesign the schema to eliminate the duplication.

Looking at the Category table reveals the *real* ***real*** problem, CategoryName is the primary key, so it will be referenced in other tables. But if CategoryName can change it's a poor choice for a primary key. Instead, use a simple auto incrementing integer as the primary key and the problem goes away.

```
create table Category (
    ID integer auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(255) not null, 
    ShippingPerPound CHAR(4),
    OffersAlowed ENUM('y', 'n'), 
);
```

Now categories can be referenced using `CategoryID integer references category(id)`. Category names can change as much as they like. Any query needing to know the category name will have to do a `join Category on Category.id = CategoryID`; simple joins like that are cheap.

> *If the Item_Number of an ITEM is changed, then the change should be reflected [in the tables which reference Item] as well.*

Same problem: if the primary key can change, it's not a good primary key. Since Item_Number is auto incremented it should never change, so you might be worrying about a problem that doesn't exist.

If Item_Number can change, then you need two columns. One for the immutable primary key, just call it `id`, and one for the mutable Item_Number. They can be the same thing for most columns, that's fine, it just adds 4 bytes to each column.

---

Note that I increased the name constraint to 255. It's a bad practice to put business rules, like size limits on names, into the database schema. The database should not be limiting design choices, and there's no technical reason to limit it: 30 characters in a `varchar(255)` takes up as much space as 30 characters in `varchar(30)`.

I'd also question why `ShippingPerPound` is a `char(4)`. It seems it should be a number, probably a `numeric(9,2)` for money. `numeric` will store exact values and does not suffer from floating point error, it's a good choice for money.

Finally, I'd caution against using an `unsigned integer` as a primary key. Yes, it doubles your keyspace, but I can *guarantee* people referencing that key will forget and use a plain, signed integer. If you hit 2 billion rows it's likely you're growing so rapidly that you'll blow through the next 2 billion much faster than the first, so it isn't worth it. If you're really concerned about keyspace, use a bigint or UUID. But this isn't something you need to worry about now, tables can be altered later if it becomes an issue. But it's unlikely to be an issue for Items as it's unlikely you'll have 2 billion items. Keyspace exhaustion is something that happens to tables that are logging things, or tracking sales, things which grow exponentially as you get more users; not manually entered warehouse data.

---

Old database guides sometimes encourage bad practices like trying to use data as a primary key, or putting unnecessary limits on storage sizes. That *might* have made sense when disk and CPU was extremely limited, or when column sizes were fixed, but it makes little sense now. An auto incremented integer primary key is a good default choice.

Comment: This is my homework and proffesor told us to use it like this. I have a problem for duplicates since that table doesent have any primary keys and it takes them from 2 different tables. ShippingPerPound is changed to ShippingPerPound DECIMAL(4,2) and i will update the diagram to show you database

Comment: @user7167038 Welp, your professor is teaching you bad practices. Sorry. OR you'll get extra credit for pointing out the problems in the schema! Hey, you never know. There are valid uses for `on update cascade`, but making up for a bad primary key isn't one of them. It's a bad schema, and primary keys that can change are bad primary keys. OTOH using `on delete cascade` to delete a Line_Item when its order or item is deleted is fine, that's enforcing data integrity. You can invite your professor on here to debate it with us, they might learn some new tricks! :)

Comment: But how can i input in table LINE_ITEM primary key if it has 2 primary keys from ItemNumber and OrderID. Sorry but i am new to this so i dont know how to setup it properly. I will ask my professor tomorrow and find what is his answer. I mean if i want to have in one table primary key(Call that table A), and in other table that primary key to became forign key(Call it table B) can i insert values in table A and that it automaticly insert in B or do i need to insert it manually?

Comment: @ZeroOne `Line_Item` should not have two primary keys. It should have two foreign keys, `ItemNumber integer references Item(ItemNumber)` and `OrderID integer references Ordered(OrderID)` (see, I forgot the unsigned part already). Simple join tables don't need primary keys, but because this contains additional data it should be treated like its own table. It should have a simple auto incremented integer primary key. As for automatic insert, you can do that with triggers, but that complicates things and you're just learning the basics. I'd suggest you start by doing everything manually.

Comment: @ZeroOne I'd suggest you ask a new question about how to redesign that schema. It is deeply flawed and getting in the way of understanding of how to design and use a schema. Also forget triggers, right now you need to learn the basics. Doesn't matter what your homework says.